# Compare two rows in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table for example like below

```
column1    column2
 110         100
  50         125
 120          80
```

I want a selection in such a way that i will get something like this

```
column1    column2    difference
 110         100           0
  50         125          50
 120          80           5
```

or just to be able to identify the **difference** between **first row of column2** and **second row of column1**

Comment: the difference as in integer subtraction? How did you calculate the results, "0" and "5"?

Comment: @YuZhang  since 100 has no other number to be subtracted from it is '0' 125 -120 =5 ,   100-50=50. subtraction is done diagonally between the columns . i actually want to apply the concept in finding the difference between a meter reading_date and the previous due_date .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `LEFT JOIN`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/2397/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    t1.*,
    difference = ISNULL(t2.column2 - t1.column1, 0)
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN Cte t2
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn + 1
```

Since there is no column to indicate the order, I added a `ROW_NUMBER`. Modify the `ORDER BY` clause to your preference.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, could be this:

```
SELECT TB.COLUMN1,TB.COLUMN2,
(ISNULL(TB2.COLUMN2,TB.COLUMN1)-TB.COLUMN1) AS 'DIF'
FROM 
(SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS 'R' FROM TEST ) TB
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS 'R' FROM TEST ) TB2
ON TB.R = TB2.R
```

**Until before the post I didn't know how dont let row_number 'order by' affected the query, but based on the above answer, now I Know it, using select null ;) thank you @Felix Pamittan**